# Is “has not been coming” or “he is not coming” correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

If a person is supposed to come but not showing up for the last two days, then which sentence is grammatically correct:

> He has not been coming for the last two days.

or

> He is not coming for the last two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*He has not been coming for the last two days* is correct because we do not use the present continuous with a time phrase like *for the last two days*
 so *he is not coming for the last two days* is wrong

You can say:

*He has not come for the last two days*

Comment: What you *mean* is correct, but "you may **preferably** say" isn't really idiomatic (even after correcting the spelling! :) I'm assuming (perhaps mistakenly) that what you're trying to imply includes both ***You may prefer to say...*** (you may prefer this alternative *as a stylistic choice*) and ***the preferred form is...*** (*other* native speakers usually prefer this alternative).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will correct it

Comment: Offhand I can't think of an elegant way to combine both those senses. ***You may prefer to use the preferred form...*** doesn't really cut it!